# Self join without double result set?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There are some duplicate (appearing twice or more) combinations of (id, name, dept_name). Note: the dept_name is nullable so there are often some nulls in that column.

I am trying to get a result of the duplicate (id, name, dept_name) combos where one record has got a null mgr_id or sal but another record of that same duplicated combo has a non-null mgr_id or sal.

This is what I have so far:

```
 select t1.id, t1.name, t1.dept_name, t1.mgr_id, t2.mgr_id, t1.sal, t2.sal from employee t1
    inner join employee t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name
    where t1.id in
    (select id from 
    (select id, name, dept_name, count(*) from employee
    group by id, name, dept_name
    having count(*) > 1))
    and (nvl(t1.mgr_id,0) <> nvl(t2.mgr_id,0) 
    or nvl(t1.sal,0) <> nvl(t2.sal,0)) 
    and t1.mgr_id is not null ;
```

If I don't leave the last line "and t1.mgr_id is not null" in the query I effectively receive the same resultset twice (which I don't want). However I need some way of incorporating the (t1.sal is not null) clause to not get the same resultset twice.

Also, note there is no PK or sequence number column where I can just go:
`t1.seq_no <> t2.seq_no`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just add the filter to the OR?:

```
 select t1.id, t1.name, t1.dept_name, t1.mgr_id, t2.mgr_id, t1.sal, t2.sal from employee t1
    inner join employee t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name
    where t1.id in
    (select id from 
    (select id, name, dept_name, count(*) from employee
    group by id, name, dept_name
    having count(*) > 1))
    and ((nvl(t1.mgr_id,0) <> nvl(t2.mgr_id,0) AND t1.mgr_id is not null) 
    or (nvl(t1.sal,0) <> nvl(t2.sal,0) AND t1.sal is not null));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROWID to distinguish the rows:

```
and t1.ROWID <> t2.ROWID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works...

```
select id,name,dept_name 
from employee 
where id in (select a.id 
             from employee a 
             where (a.sal is NULL or a.mgr_id is NULL) 
and a.id in (select b.id 
             from employee b 
             where b.sal is not NULL or b.mgr_id is not NULL));
```

Comment: What output you are getting from the query?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have 4 situations.

- sal null, dept null
- sal null, dept nonnull
- sal nonnull, dept null
- sal nonnull, dept nonnull

And you have only two sets of columns to compare.

Somehow you'll get duplicates.

As a hibrid solution you can try:

```
select distinct t1.id, t1.name, t1.dept_name, t1.mgr_id, t2.mgr_id, t1.sal, t2.sal from employee t1
    inner join employee t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name
    where t1.id in
    (select id from 
    (select id, name, dept_name, count(*) from employee
    group by id, name, dept_name
    having count(*) > 1))
    and (nvl(t1.mgr_id,0) <> nvl(t2.mgr_id,0) 
    or nvl(t1.sal,0) <> nvl(t2.sal,0)) ;
```

(note the distinct)

or, you can use:

```
select distinct t1.id, t1.name, t1.dept_name, t1.mgr_id 
from employee t1
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

and you'll see the difference between rows.

Comment: Distinct didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

I created the following post to show how I normally find duplicates in the same table.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sql-query-trick-to-find-duplicate-records/

I find the criteria I want to find matches on (MyName in example below) and then use another field to determine which values are not equal (normally an ID Field).

```
select 
t1.ID,
t1.MyName,
t2.MyName,
t2.ID
from
Table t1 
inner join Table t2 on t1.MyName = t2.MyName and t1.ID <> t2.ID
```

Note that this can return what appears to be duplicates - but tweaking the query a bit can resolve that.  Also I normally use this for spot checking data versus production queries.

Comment: I believe this will return the same record twice. As per your link the first 2 records are essentially the same.

Comment: That's what I said in my comments under the query above.  :)